# How do I add up two scatter points with the same values of x but different values of y?

Tags: matlab

On a stem plot, how can I add points that have the same values of `x` but different values of `y`?

For example, given the following code:

```
x = [1 2 3 6 6 4 5];
y = [3 6 1 8 9 4 2];
stem(x,y);
```

If you plot `x`, and `y`, this will be the output:

[image]

I want to add up `(6,8)` and `(6,9)` so it becomes `(6,17)`, just like what the image is showing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your input data and your graph don't match.  Specifically `X` and `Y` have different lengths.  You can't use `stem` with different length vectors.

Comment: i'm sorry i already edit the y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with `x` and `y` so you can bin or group like entries together that share the same `x`.  Once these values are binned, you can sum all of the values that share the same bin together.  As such, we see that for `x = 6`, we have `y = 8` and `y = 9`.  `accumarray` allows you to group multiple `y` values together that share the same `x`.  Once these values are grouped, you then apply a function to all of the values in the same group to produce a final output for each group.  In our case, we want to sum them, so we need to use the `sum` function:

```
x = [1 2 3 6 6 4 5];
y = [3 6 1 8 9 4 2];
Z = accumarray(x(:), y(:), [], @sum);
stem(unique(x), Z);
xlim([0 7]);
```

We use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on `X` so that we have no repeats for `X` when plotting the `stem` plot.  `unique` also has the behaviour of **sorting** your `x` values.  Doing `x(:)` and `y(:)` is so that you can make your input data either as row or column vectors independently.  `accumarray` accepts only **column** vectors (or matrices, but we won't go there) and so doing `x(:)` and `y(:)` ensures that both inputs are column vectors.

We get:

[image]

The above code assumes that `x` is **integer** and starting at 1.  If it isn't, then use the third output of `unique` to assign each number a unique ID, then run this through `accumarray`.  When you're done, use the output of `accumarray` like normal:

```
[xu,~,id] = unique(x);
Z = accumarray(id, y(:), [], @sum);
stem(xu, Z);
```

Comment: hi, can you do it in java netbean?